# Submit form using element without ID

Tags: forms, vba, excel, internet-explorer

Context: Hi community. I have a problem. My boss asked me to pull names from some database using employee's ID. That wouldn't be a problem only if the access to the database wasn't through form written in PHP. The second one is that I have to pull about 10k of results. I calculated the time needed for this and got 55 hours of dull work. And I am speaking of perfect performance either of me and the server I am about to connect to. I thought it would be perfect if vba could do this for me. The situation is as follows.

Problem: Form is located on page on the intranet. User inputs the id and when clicks Ok button a table is generated (not present before submit), where name of the employee appears. The problem is that the "Ok" button does not have an ID so using GetElementById is out of the question. I need to submit the form somehow. Will somebody help?

The code:

```
Sub submitFeedback3()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "SomePHP.php"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim formx As Object
    Set doc = IE.document

    IE.document.getElementById("search_usrn").Value = "someID"

    IE.document.all.Item("Ok").Click

    Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I set a watch in IE.document and it revealed structure. I was able o find the submit button, but I am not able to trigger it.

It was in IE.document > forms > item 1 > item 5

This has folowing attributes I was able to find it with:

```
outerHTML "INPUT type=submit value=Ok"
type "submit"
unique id "ms__id3"
value "Ok"
```

Can i trigger it somehow using these? Or is there any other way?
Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Was able to manage it minutes after I posted the question. Just for others trying to address this issue. If submit button has no ID you can force the document to submit using just

```
document.forms(numberOfForm).submit
```

I knew that but I did it poorly. Do not repeat my mistake, the numbers start with 0 not 1. So the correct number for only form on the page was 0.

Comment: That's a separate question, please post it as a new one.